# PowerShell-based Azure Function ouput to OneDrive

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I have a very simple "hello world" type function. In the run.ps1

```
$request = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -ExpandProperty ip
$out = "$env:TEMP\zhello.txt"
Set-Content -value $request -path $out
Out-File -Encoding ASCII $out
```

and function.json has this:

```
{
  "type": "apiHubFile",
  "name": "outputFile",
  "path": "output_{file}",
  "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

It runs successfully with no errors but the file isn't in my OneDrive. Also tried using Azure Blob Storage as an output. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Out-File` command doesn't have any value to write to your `$out` file path.  It's probably erasing the file created by `Set-Content`.

Try commenting out `Set-Content` and just use `$request | Out-File -Encoding ASCII $out` instead.

If that doesn't solve it, make sure your first line is actually retrieving data and assigning it to `$request` like you think it is.

**Edit**

You can also try writing `$out` to host to make sure you know exactly where it's placing the file.  Implementing these suggestions renders this code:

```
$request = "hello world"
$out = "$env:TEMP\zhello.txt"
Write-Host $out
$request | Out-File -Encoding ASCII $out
```

This produces the file as expected for me.

If that still doesn't work for you, confirm you have permissions to write to that file location by trying something like `"hello world 2" > "$env:TEMP\zhello.txt"`

Comment: I changed it to $request = "Hello World." so it now most definitely has a value. Also took your suggestions to comment out Set-Content and just pipe it.
It still runs successfully but no files show up (in Blob or OneDrive)

Comment: See my update with a few more suggestions and a complete example.

Comment: Could you post your function.json ? I'm using the exact code you have, I see my file is there in $env:TEMP but doesn't get outputted to Blob/OneDrive.

Comment: I was just testing on my local machine.  It's strange, since it looks like $env:TEMP should be available in Azure Functions according to this guy: https://justingrote.github.io/2017/12/25/Powershell-Azure-Functions-The-Missing-Manual.html

Comment: The issue isn't using $env:TEMP, that is working just fine. The issue is that the file that's there, never shows up in Azure Blob/OneDrive/Dropbox using a timer trigger (or running manually). I've only seen the HTTP trigger work as expected (returns response in $res http stream but I need the file). Looking to see if Azure Automation can do this instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following post that helps answer my original question: [Outputting a file with an Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830321/outputting-a-file-with-an-azure-function#41860115)

My **run.ps1** now looks like this:

```
$request = "hello world"
$filename = "$env:TEMP\zhello.txt"
$request | Out-File  $filename
$base64string = [Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filename))

$response = ConvertTo-JSON @{
    Body=$base64string;
    Headers=@{
    # unfortunately it seems functions does not support 'filename=...'
    'Content-Disposition'='attachment'; 
    # you would use application/octet-stream, but because it's converted to JSON you lose binary content
    'Content-Type'='text/plain';        
    };
}
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $outputFile -inputObject $response
```

A file does get placed into my OneDrive, however it's contents are simply this

```
{
    "Headers":  {
                    "Content-Type":  "text/plain",
                    "Content-Disposition":  "attachment"
                },
    "Body":  "//5oAGUAbABsAG8AIAB3AG8AcgBsAGQADQAKAA=="
}
```

Now I can take that "Body" and create the file from it locally:

```
$encodedText = "//5oAGUAbABsAG8AIAB3AG8AcgBsAGQADQAKAA=="
$Content = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($encodedText)
Set-Content -Path $env:temp\my-file.txt -Value $Content -Encoding Byte
```

But that defeats the purpose of the function, I might as well run everything locally since I need to run this "decode" snippet locally.

EDIT:

After some more testing I discovered that the MAIN reason that I wasn't able to output a file before was due to my function.json using the default value of {file}. Once I hardcoded this to "zhello.txt" I got that file in OneDrive with the contents specified by $response. Still, I need to figure out a way to specify the outputFile name dynamically (in my run.ps1).